# broke during upgrade; what command do I use?

Tags: unity, upgrade, apt

during the upgrade to 12:10 it froze and i had to reboot.
What do I do to reset apt and reinstall the broken things?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#fix any broken packages
sudo apt-get -f install

#cleanup any unnecessary packages
sudo apt-get autoremove

#kick off the upgrade, if available
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: unity (Ubuntu) wont load, but Gnome classic will.

Comment: Make sure your data is backed up, start the upgrade again, and see if it upgrades Unity to a working state.

Comment: nope, starts loading and then just... stops

Comment: what stops, the OS, or the upgrade?  Is there any download activity?  It's going to have to download a *lot* of data to do the upgrade.